# having elevated priority and general @audio permssion in rc.local

Tags: sound, bash, permissions, scripts

I am trying to run jackd instance from /etc/rc.local (along with a few other applications) from a custom made init script.

The system is ubuntustudio and I have setup everything to have elevated permissions when executing applications from the @audio group.

so when I am logged on, I see this:

```
nass@starkill:~$ ulimit -r -l
real-time priority              (-r) 95
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
```

which is expected and I can execute the script I wrote.

but, when I execute my script from /etc/rc.local as

```
su - nass -c "ulimits -r -l cd audio_setup/scripts ; bash ./start_audio"
```

then my user does not (yet?) have elevated permissions.

```
real-time priority              (-r) 0
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
```

is there a script I can run before my start_audio script to elevate my permissions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit  this file as root:

/etc/pam.d/su

Search and uncomment this line in the file removing #:

```
# session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Reboot and test.